# how to make data offline permanent

Tags: html, local-storage, offline, indexeddb

Making localStorage and/or IndexedDB data offline permanent?

Is it possible to make localStorage and/or IndexedDB offline data permanent?

I am planning to make a completely offline HTML5 app and want the data to never get deleted, unless and otherwise the user knowingly does so.

I do not want the data to be deleted even after the app is closed, system is shutdown.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) [for either of these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB)?

Answer (score 2):

> ...want the data to never get deleted, unless and otherwise the user
>   knowingly does so.

The Storage API allow requesting a "persistent" permission for your origin. If granted, the semantics are that the data stored in certain APIs (local storage, Indexed DB, Cache, etc) is preserved until an explicit user action (like clearing storage), which appears to match your needs.

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager/persist

Note that this is a new web platform API. It was recently added to Firefox (57) and Chrome (55), but is not present in Edge or Safari. Also note that Chrome does not currently show prompts for this permission request; it uses heuristics about the web app to determine if the request should be granted or not rather than asking the user to make the decision.

The specification is at: https://storage.spec.whatwg.org

The spec gives a background on how storage could work in browsers, i.e. by default an origin's data is "best effort", meaning preserved until the browser needs to clear it (due to space constraints, etc). The actual behavior of browsers varies significantly.